# how to call main controllers function from child directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to call method `adddepartment` which is in controller.I am calling this method from `myCreateDialog.html`.

My second directive in under the first directive. I am able to call departments method which is in controller from `myDept` directive. but not able to call `adddepartment` method of controller from `myCreateDialog` directive.

How do i call this method?

```
  myApp.controller('departmentController', ['$scope', 'departmentService' ,
              function ($scope, departmentService) {

                  $scope.departments = departmentService.departments;
                  var a, b;
                  //Add New Department
                  $scope.adddepartment = function (emps) {


                      departmentService.adddepartment(depts);

                      $scope.depts = "";
                  };
             }]);

            myApp.directive("myDept", function () {
                return {
                    restrict: "E",
                    scope:{
                        department:"="
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'Template/Alldepartment.html',
                    replace: false,        
                    transclude:true, 

                link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {}    
                };

            });

            myApp.directive("myCreateDialog", function () {
                return {
                    restrict: "E",
                    scope:{
                        adddepartment: "&"
                    },
                    templateUrl: 'Template/myCreateDialog.html',
                    link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {

                    }

                };

            });
      App.js
            var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
            myApp.config(['$routeProvider',
              function ($routeProvider) {
                  $routeProvider.

                       when('/Employee', {
                           templateUrl: 'Template/Employee.html',
                           controller: 'employeeController'
                       }).
                  when('/Department', {
                      templateUrl: 'Template/Department.html',
                      controller: 'departmentController'
                  })


              }]);

    Department.html
            <my-dept department="departments">
                <p>This text is coming by transclude</p>
            </my-dept>

    Alldepartment.html
        <div>
            <div class='myTransclude' ng-transclude></div>
            <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#crtdept">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Create New Department
            </button>

        </div><br />


        <!--Display department data into table-->
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table  table-bordered table-striped table-hover ">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="success ">
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Technology</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="dept in department">
                        <td>{{dept.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{dept.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{dept.technology}}</td>

                        <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editemp" ng-click="empedit(employee,employees.indexOf(employee))">

                                <span class="text-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit 
                            </button>
                            <button class="btn btn-link" ng-click="deleteemp(employees.indexOf(employee))">

                                <span class=" text-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash "> Delete</span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <!--myCreateDialog directive for showing dialog for creating department-->
        <my-create-dialog adddepartment="adddepartment(depts)"></my-create-dialog>

    myCreateDialog.html

    <div class="modal fade" id="crtdept">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" style="color:red" class=" close" data-dismiss="modal"> &times;</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title">Create Employee</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" role="form" ng-submit="adddepartment(emps)">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 has-success">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Name" ng-model="emps.empnames" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 has-success">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your email" ng-model="emps.empemails" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class=" form-group">

                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">City:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 has-success">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your City" ng-model="emps.empcitys" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Department:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 has-success">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Department" ng-model="emps.empdepts" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Technology:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 has-success">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your Technology" ng-model="emps.emptechs" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Create</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You really need to start using camel case for your naming, adddepartment should be AddDepartment for a service and addDepartment for function on your controller

Comment: ok.. will change it. but can u help me why i am not able to call controller's function from "myCreateDialog" directive. i have used "&" for calling function.

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: sorry there is too much of code..so cant setup...i have included all files above..

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your departmentService into your directive and call it from there

```
myApp.directive("myCreateDialog", function (departmentService) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: 'Template/myCreateDialog.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
          scope.adddepartment = function (emps) {
            departmentService.adddepartment(depts);
            scope.depts = "";
          };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: But why i am not able to access adddepartment(depts). i am able to access departments  from directive. so why cant this.?